# How to post and get the Image Data to the Aspnetcore Web api server using react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, react-hook-form

I am making a register form using react hook forms and I want to send the data to the ASP.NetCore API Server. For posting the form I am using Axios and react-hook-form. My functionality is working indeed and form is getting submitted to the server. But the problem is it is sending as null for the "ProfilePhoto" field from the form itself. I want to send the image data as the URL so that I could easily get the image back from the API server using the get request and could embed that object returned from the server into the `<img src=""/>` field. Could anyone suggest me some workarounds, for posting and effectively getting the posted image back to the user inside of the react component.
Here is what I tried so far...

Inside of my axios component as - typescript

```
axios.defaults.baseURL='http://localhost:5000/api/';
    const responseBody = (response : AxiosResponse) => response.data; 
    const Account = {
     register : (values : any, config : {}) => axios.post("Visitor/register", values, 
     config).then(responseBody),
 }

export default Account;
```

and here's my register.tsx component utilizing the react-hook-form

```
export default function Register() {
//local state for image preview
const [seeImage, setSeeImage] = useState("");
const defaultImage : string = 'InitialRoles/Thumbnail.png';
const {register, handleSubmit,
formState: {errors, isValid, isSubmitting}} = useForm({mode : 'all'});
const config = {
  headers : {
    "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"
  } 
}

const SubmitForm = async (data : FieldValues) => {
const formData = new FormData();
const imageInput = document.getElementById('imageFile') as HTMLInputElement;
  try{
    formData.append('profilePhoto', imageInput.files?.item(0) as File);
    console.log(formData);
    await agent.Visitor.register(data, config);
  }catch(error : any){
  console.log(error);
  }
};

const ShowImagePreview = (event : any) => {
if(event.target.files[0]){
setSeeImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
}};

return ( <>
                 <TextField
                  autoComplete="name"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  label="Full Name"
                  autoFocus
                  {...register('name', {
                    required : 'Please enter your full name'
                  })}
                />
      
                 <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="Username"
                  label="Username"
                  placeholder='Your awesome username'
                  autoComplete="username"
                  {...register('userName', {
                    required : 'Please enter a cool username'
                  })}
                  error={!!errors.userName}
                />

                       <Button
                       variant="contained" 
                       component="label" 
                       endIcon={<Photo />}
                       fullWidth = {true}
                       disableElevation = {true}
                       sx={{width : '84%', mx: 2}}>
                        <input hidden multiple type="file" 
                         accept= "image/*"
                         {...register('profilePhoto', {
                          required : 'Profile photo is required',
                          onChange : ShowImagePreview,
                         })}
                         id ="imageFile"
                        />
                        {"Upload Image"}
                     </Button>
//preview                    
<img className='profileImage' src={seeImage ? seeImage : 'InitialRoles/Thumbnail.png'} alt ={/*formdata?.profileName*/ ""} width ="165px" height = "163px" />

               </>)}
```

My data is hitting the server and so the database. But the problem is I am sending the null object back to the server into the 'ProfilePhoto' field. How could I send the image object(supported object which an 'IFormFile' could accept).

I have Asp.Netcore Server with register modal

```
public class Visitor : IdentityUser
{
   [Required, MaxLength(200)]
   public string Name { get; set; } 

   public IFormFile ProfilePhoto { get; set; }

}
```

//userName is coming from IdentityUser for authentication.
Everything is working fine, how could I get the Image object to be stored into the server as the url so that I could return that url to the client to display it some later time?

This is the payload that is coming back from the server after a successful registration.

```
name: bob
userName: bob123
email: bob@test.com
profilePhoto: [object FileList] //this is sending as 'null'
password: Pa$$w0rd
```

All Suggestions are Welcome : )

Answer (score 0):

> When you want pass file, you must using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Read documents about formData in axios [documents](https://stackabuse.com/axios-multipart-form-data-sending-file-through-a-form-with-javascript/)

Comment: Hii, my files are going to the server and it is showing me the response of 201 as well. But when checking the uploads folder, it is giving me as null into "profilePhoto: null'.I tried using swagger, it is working there as well

Comment: @HimanshuSharma Your action must `POST`, can you attach your action ?